# “The specified account name is not a member of the group”

Tags: active-directory

Good afternoon,

I was hoping someone could help?

I have a domain local security group with a user object as a member that is from another domain. There is a trust in place between the two domains. When I remove the user object from the security group using dsa.msc it appears to have been removed successfully. However, using PowerShell or ADSIEdit the user object is still present. When I attempt to remove the user object from the security group using PowerShell or ADSIEdit I get the following error:

[image]

How can I remove the user object from the security group? Any idea of what the issue could be? I seem to be able to remove other user objects from the trusted domain and they don't show as members when I use PowerShell or ADSIEdit but I haven't tried removing anymore other than this particular user object at the moment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help if you could share the code producing this error.

Comment: Hi Clayton, here is the PowerShell cmdlets used (I've replaced the actual domain names and user object names but hopefully highlights the same issue)

$user = get-aduser -server domain-b -identity user-b

remove-adgroupmember -identity "security-group-in-domain-a" -members $user

Sorry, not sure how to do spaces/line breaks in this comment reply?